# How do you calculate the means of a 2D numpy array using broadcasting and/or numpy functions?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, array-broadcasting

I have a 2-dimensional numpy array of integers and I would like to compute a 1-dimensional numpy array containing the means of each array of the 2-dimensional array, so for example

```
array([[1, 2]
       [3, 4]])
```

would return

```
array([1.5, 3.5])
```

Currently, I am using a list comprehension to do this

```
[sum(i) / len(i) for i in lst]
```

which works just fine, but I am curious if there is a way to do this using broadcasting and/or numpy functions. That would also be faster for large arrays, which I plan to use this function on.  Any insights would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])`

`np.mean(a, axis=1)`

This will give you the expected result.

In a 2-D array, `axis=0` indicates the column and `axis=1` indicates the row.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that `np.mean` had an `axis` parameter. I guess I should read the documentation before I come to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Welcome. In fact the axis parameter is available with many other functions like `min`, `max`, `sum`, `median`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
np.mean(myfavoritearray, axis=1)
```

should do the trick.

Comment: or equivalent but a bit more concise: `myfavoritearray.mean(axis=0)`

Comment: Thanks! I think you mean `axis=1` though. `axis=0` seems to be averaging the first element in each array, the second element in each array, and so on.